# No route matches {:action=>"evaluate", :controller=>"drills"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, action

When using a menu to allow selection of a method "evaluate" from a controller "Drills" I get the error message
No route matches {:action=>"evaluate", :controller=>"drills"

The controller

```
class DrillsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :load_drill, except: [:index, :new, :create]

authorize_resource

rescue_from GeoPosition::Error::InvalidDegreesError,
          GeoPosition::Error::InvalidMinutesError,
          GeoPosition::Error::InvalidSecondsError do |e|
  flash[:message] = e.message
  redirect_to :back
 # can only be placed here
 end

def evaluate
  evaluation_assumption = Evaluation.generate_projection(assumption_params)
  if evaluation_assumption.valid?
    result_list = Evaluation.generate_projection(@drill.drill_interests,
                                               evaluation_assumption)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: results_list}
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: []}
    end
  end
end
.. controller continues
```

Using CONTROLLER=drills rake routes I get

```
drill_evaluate POST   /drills/:drill_id/evaluate(.:format) drills#evaluate
       drills GET    /drills(.:format)                    drills#index
             POST   /drills(.:format)                    drills#create
   new_drill GET    /drills/new(.:format)                drills#new
  edit_drill GET    /drills/:id/edit(.:format)           drills#edit
       drill GET    /drills/:id(.:format)                drills#show
             PUT    /drills/:id(.:format)                drills#update
             DELETE /drills/:id(.:format)                drills#destroy
```

The menu view to try to get to Drill - Evaluate is drill_evalate_path as below

```
....
<ul class="t-nav">
      <li class="tab <%=(tab_id == 'Drill Information') ? 'active' : '' %>">
          <%= link_to "Drill Information", drill_stakes_path %></li>
      <li class="tab <%=(tab_id == 'Investor Room') ? 'active' : '' %>">
          <%= link_to "Expanded Investor Room", 
          drill_evaluate_path %></li>
    </ul> 
....
```

Within the menu view I have tried a whole lot of different options including

```
<li class="tab <%=(tab_id == 'Investor Room') ? 'active' : '' %>">
          <%= link_to "Expanded Investor Room", 
          drills_path, action: => :evaluate %></li>
```

Which tries to execute the "create" action.

I thought I could use the left most column from the Rake Routes output with link_to to take me to the appropriate page.  I must be wrong.  How do I set a link_to so it takes me to the evaluate action in the Drills controller ?

thanks in advance
Pierre

Comment: Could you paste your config/routes.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a member route, which means you have to give it the `id` of the drill you expect.

Ie:

```
drill_evaluate_path(id)
#or
drill_evaluate_path(drill_object)
```

It's clearly written here (see `drill_id` param):

```
drill_evaluate POST   /drills/:drill_id/evaluate(.:format) drills#evaluate
```